# How to use credentialId to retrieve the username/password in my own jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Now I have below codes which can retrieve the credentialId. I wanto get the username and password of the credential and pass to other places.

```
        StandardCredentials c = CredentialsMatchers.firstOrNull(
            CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
                    StandardCredentials.class,
                    Jenkins.getActiveInstance(),
                    ACL.SYSTEM,
                    Collections.<DomainRequirement>emptyList()
            ),
            CredentialsMatchers.allOf(
                    CredentialsMatchers.always(),
                    CredentialsMatchers.withId(credentialsId)
            )

    );
    //NameProvider np = new NameProvider();
    logger.println(c.getId());
```

Some one please help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got a solution.

```
// Retrieve the credentials
    StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials crd = CredentialsMatchers.firstOrNull(
            CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
                    StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials.class,
                    Jenkins.getActiveInstance(),
                    ACL.SYSTEM,
                    Collections.<DomainRequirement>emptyList()
            ),
            CredentialsMatchers.allOf(
                    CredentialsMatchers.always(),
                    CredentialsMatchers.withId(credentialsId)
            )

    );
    //crd.getUsername();
    //crd.getPassword();
```